# how would I generate a repeatable encryption key?

Tags: python

I need to sent my friend Bob the number 42, my code will use a pre-shared key generate a random number to encrypt the message (42) and decrypt it on Bobs end. the only problem is, I have no clue how to generate a repeatable encryption key in python.

Comment: I really hope this is just for academic purposes.

Comment: [Key derivation functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) should return the same result with the same input, otherwise you couldn't decrypt.

Comment: @Haveaniceday A new random public key is generated every time you call the encrypt method, the method returns the public key and the encrypted text joined together in a single string, before the whole thing is encoded in base64. So it is expected for the `encrypt()` method to return a different string every time it is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Crypto to encrypt a message using AES.

```
import hashlib, base64
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

class AESCipher():
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.private_key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode()).digest()
        self.bs = AES.block_size

    def encrypt(self, data):
        # generate public key
        public_key = Random.new().read(self.bs)

        # setup AES Cipher using public key and private key
        cipher = AES.new(self.private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, public_key)

        # enrpyt the data and convert to base64
        return base64.b64encode(public_key + cipher.encrypt(self.pad(data).encode()))

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        # convert encrypted data to base 64
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)

        # get public key
        public_key = enc[:AES.block_size]

        # setup AES Cipher using public and private key
        cipher = AES.new(self.private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, public_key)

        # decrypt data using the public key
        return self.unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[AES.block_size:])).decode("utf-8")

    def pad(self, s):
        # pads data so that it's a multiple of 16
        return s + (self.bs - len(s) % self.bs) * chr(self.bs - len(s) % self.bs)

    def unpad(self, s):
        # removes padding
        return s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]

cipher = AESCipher("your secret key")
```

Here I encrypt some text, the public key with the encrypted text is joined and returned from the `encrypt` method, you can then send the returned text to Bob, to decrypt the text bob then just needs to run the `decrypt` method.

```
>>> cipher.encrypt("your message")
b'HYfUkcd//CaRquG9AhReR8bJYdVQdcGWRAjcp9AstLs='
>>> output = cipher.encrypt("your message")
>>> output
b'RVTK7L7ZDw9DzvuXuj8zYPZJjBO/A0N3l5N1hp9LY6U='
>>> cipher.decrypt(output)
'your message'
>>>
```

Comment: @Topaco no point being nit picky, I feel like your complaining about a trivial variable name for the sake of complaining. Please by all means feel free to change the variables name in your own implementation.